# LaTeX snippets \begin{description} won't work in Geany

Tags: latex, code-snippets, geany

I've written the following snippet to work with the description environment under LaTeX.

```
description= \\begin{description}\n%ws%\\item %cursor%\n\\end{description}
```

However, when I try to use it, it results in:

```
\begin
    \item
\end
```

Which is not expected. Other snippets, like

```
enumerate=\\begin{enumerate}\n%ws%\\item %cursor%\n\\end{enumerate}
```

work very well.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure? Actually I've just tried it and it's working. Maybe you have defined {description] somewhere. However, I think it's off topic for here and maybe something for the bug tracker of Geany

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because either it's a bug in software or something issue related to user's configuration not part of this question.

Comment: Hi, {description} has not been defined elsewhere. Anyway, I will submit this to the Geany bug tracker. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, it was not a bug. See my answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this issue.
In geany, the sequence {description} is a substitution (see [this link](https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#template-wildcards), for more information about substitution sequences).

The best way to avoid the issue I raised is to replace { and } by `{ob}` and `{cb}` respectively, in the `snippets.conf` file.

In my example, I just had to replace {description} by {ob}description{cb}, and it now works very well. See [this link](https://github.com/geany/geany/issues/1671) for the discussion on Github bug tracking.